# 1995 Yamaha virago 535 Fuel pump problem

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, yamaha, virago

On my 1995 Yamaha virago 535, why does the fuel pump click 10 or so times before trying to start?  I've replaced the fuel pump and fuel pump relay.  It still has the clicking issue and will not start.

Comment: You might check [this link](http://powersports-blog.denniskirk.com/5821/motorcycle-2/steps-take-motorcycle-wont-start) for tips on what to do with a motorcycle that won't start. It starts with the simple and cheap and moves into more costly problems.

Comment: You say you replaced the fuel pump. Did you know for sure that wasn't working when you replaced it?

Comment: Thank you Poisson Fish.  When I replaced the pump I was not sure if that was the problem.  I will check out the link you sent.

Answer (score 3):

Many fuel pumps do this by default and are 'priming' the fuel system for start by increasing the pressure behind the injectors.

For most motorcycles with fuel pumps this is standard operating procedure.

Comment: Though he is curious about the fuel pump, it appears as though the question is mostly related to problems starting the bike after replacing the pump. Do you have any tips for complications that might arise after doing this?

Comment: Perhaps it's not the fuel pump.  There is very little information here.

Comment: That's what I'm guessing too.

Comment: I have checked the plugs.  They are fine. It turns over but just will not go.  The fuel in it is only a few days old.  It is on the brink of starting...

Comment: When you say that you have checked the plugs, could you explain what the check is?  Do you have spark?  Did you clean them?  Visual inspection?  Providing detail will help us to understand what you've done and what you mean.  Thanks